# Did Kolmogorov complexity influence the development of communication complexity?

Tags: biographical-details, computer-science, kolmogorov

I was reading a wikipedia article about [communication complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_complexity) and it seems to me that it bears some resemblance to [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).
Was the founder of communication complexity influenced by Kolmogorov complexity?

Comment: [Yao's paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/800135.804414) does not cite Kolmogorov directly, but he cites Rabin's Probabilistic Algorithms from Algorithms and Complexity volume, which is dedicated to computational complexity. So yes, he was aware of it. But Kolmogorov aimed at "intrinsic" complexity, rather than information transfers *a la* Shannon that Yao uses, and the two measures are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: How are they "Orthogonal to each other"? Is it only because Kolmogorov complexity is thought to measure the intrinsic complexity of things?

Comment: "*Unlike in computational complexity theory, communication complexity is not concerned with the amount of computation performed by Alice or Bob, or the size of the memory used*".

Comment: But still they are both kind of concerned with the amount of information needed to describe an object, either via communication or through a program. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, any two things are related if you make it vague enough.

Comment: @conifold I thought that the concept of communicating the minimum number of information in order to create construct regardless the computation time and memory is very similar as that of the minimum sized program creating that construct in a programming language that allows certain set of functions. Of course there may be other theories that are closer to communication complexity than Kolmogorov complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Conifold in the comments, the answer of the history seems likely that Yao was surely aware of Kolmogorov complexity at the time, but that the introduction of communication complexity was more motivated by communication between agents or processors than any connection with Kolmogorov complexity.

That said, there are some relations between the two concepts, for example:

- Vereshchagin [Randomized Communication Complexity of Approximating Kolmogorov Complexity](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-06686-8_28) (preprint of full version available [here](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2013/178/))
- Kaplan & Laplante, [Kolmogorov complexity and combinatorial methods in communication complexity](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2010.10.044)
- Mora, Briegel, & Kraus, [Quantum Kolmogorov complexity and its applications](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219749907003171)

Answer (score 1):

The first link says that

> communication complexity studies the amount of *communication* required to solve a problem when the problem is *distributed* between two or more parties.

Whilst the second link says that

> Kolmogorov complexity of an object, such as a piece of text, is the length of the shortest computer program... that produces the object as output. It is a measure of the computational resource...

Had you read further down in the first link you would have discovered:

> Note that unlike computational complexity theory, communication complexity is not concerned with the amount of computation performed by Alice or Bob, or the size of the memory used, as we assume nothing about the computational power of Alice or Bob.

So,  no, the two concepts are not at all related other than sharing the word 'complexity' in their names. And that connection is spurious.